# How to remove the gridlines, row numbers, column headers, scroll bars and sheets tab from the excel web access webpart?

Tags: 2013, excel-web-access-webpart

We are displaying an excel sheet via excel web access web part on a sharepoint page. There is only 1 excel sheet containing 2 charts.

This appears like a normal excel doc with grid lines, 2 charts and tabs below for sheets. How do I remove the gridlines, row numbers, column headers, scroll bars and sheets tab from the excel web access webpart for better look?

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. Like grid lines, scroll bars, row and column headers are handled in Excel, as I explained in my answer below.

Comment: duplicate here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144392/how-to-remove-the-scroll-bars-row-numbers-and-columns-headers-from-excel-web-ac

Comment: @teylyn Thank you! I've merged these two questions into one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best way is to make those charts as named Parts and then specify that name in Excel web access part . You should see only that Chart. Also in web part setting if you chose toolbar none, you wont see file tab or other excel function. It will be visible as plain Web chart and they wont know its actual excel file.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Excel settings to hide the gridlines. Define a range that you want to display in web access web part and configure the web part to show that range only.

Answer (score 1):

This has to be done in the actual Excel file.

Row and column headers are easy removed, to get rid of the scroll bars i think you have to use multiple sheet to keep the content size from generating a scroll bar, or if you can set the web part width and height in SharePoint so the whole sheet is visible and thus removing the scroll bar.

[How to display or hide Row & Column Headers in Microsoft Excel?](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/662-excel-display-hide-headings.html)

[Scroll bars in Excel services web part](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/854b1249-ef1f-463a-a649-cc84a0ce65a9/scroll-bars-in-excel-services-web-part)