# How to remove the scroll bars, row numbers and columns headers from excel web access webpart?

Tags: 2013, excel-web-access-webpart

We are displaying few charts on an excel sheet.

How to remove the scroll bars, row numbers and columns headers from excel web access webpart?

Comment: same question asked here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/144389/how-to-remove-the-gridlines-and-sheets-tab-from-the-excel-web-access-webpart/144390#144390